# Bundle not found when updating from Symfony 2.0 to Symfony2.1 via composer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm updating my app from Symfony2.0 to Symfony2.1.

When I run composer install I receive a fatal exception about `JMS/SerializerBundle` not being found when it reaches the generating autoload files step. I think `cache:clear` is causing this.

I've added it to `composer.json`:

```js
"jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
```

And in my *appKernel*:

```php
new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
```

I basically followed the steps.

I also can not find the file in the vendor directory. The composer stated 'Nothing to install or update' though. It does not matter if I put in a version number. Think this is the same for the stof doctrine extension.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try rm -rf `vendors/*`, and then - `php composer.phar install`

Comment: That did not solve the problem. Vendor dir was removed on starting the update.

Comment: Having only `"jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master"` in a `composer.json` file works for me, i.e. the bundle is in the vendor dir and should be autoloaded correctly. Could you post your composer.json, if it is possible? I will try it on my side.

Comment: What `minimum-stability` value do you have in your `composer.json`?

Comment: Did you tried to delete the "web/bundles" dir and then clear the cache? Moreover, try to use **update** option instead of **install**.

Comment: Indeed, I think if a composer.lock file is present that doesn't contain JMS Serializer then it wont be installed; but you should get a warning when you execute `php composer.phar install` telling you to run `php composer.phar update`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting symfony to 2.1.0 allowed me to install the extra repositories.